# Stack operations using an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, stack

I was looking around online and found a class to use ArrayLists in Stack operations. After looking up the arraylist I noticed the `<E>` designation there too. I followed it all the way back to Collection and I don't understand what the `<E>` would be in this example:

```
public class MyStack<E> {
   private ArrayList<E> arrList;

   public MyStack() {
       arrList = new ArrayList<E>();
}

   public void push(E item) {
       arrList.add(item);
}

... more methods...
}
```

What does "E" refer to? If it was explained in the docs I either missed it or just don't understand it.

Comment: You know, you already have a [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class in Java?

Comment: ... and here's [a link to the API reference for the Stack class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Comment: @RohitJain you know that it would be better to use a [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) implemented by [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) because it doesn't inherit from `java.util.Vector` as the proposed `java.util.Stack`?

Comment: what are you asking about exactly? "What does refer to?" doesn't seem to be a valid sentence...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza.. Yeah that is true.

Comment: @mantrid sorry, the < seemed to make my E invisible in the middle of that sentence.

Comment: Have you read about generics?

Comment: E is a type variable, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java to learn about generics

Comment: It would be good to know that implementing your own Stack is good as a programming excercise or homework but it's bad if you're doing this for a personal or professional project, remember **to not reinvent the wheel**.

Comment: you are asking for the E, and not the question in the subject. Please consider changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<E>` represents the type of data that you will use in your `Stack`. The simple example will be enough:

```
MyStack<String> myStack = new MyStack<String>();
myStack.push("Sample string");
```

This is called [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm in a beginner course and I cannot remember coming across that before. In fact, I skimmed through the reading list and not one mention of it in that (there are hundreds of links though, could be in there)

Answer (score 1):

These are [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). The let you not have to specify in advance exactly which type of object you want to store in the data structure. You only need to know the Object Type when an instance of the stack is created like so

```
MyStack<String> stack = new MyStack<String>();
```

Now you can only put Strings in the stack:

```
stack.add("A String");
```

Trying to add anything else will give you a compilation error:

```
stack.add(new Integer());  // Compiler error
stack.add(2); // Compiler error
```

Answer (score 0):

is the data or objects you are pushing or popping from the stack. You can find more on this subject in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/